# CasperJS exit() quit bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, casperjs

I'm running casperJS within a bat file but it seems that calling exit() in casperJS also exit() my bat file.

My bat file is:

```
casperJS %1 %2 %3
echo test
convert %3 -resize "20%x20%" %3
```

And it execute this .js file:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var casper = require("casper").create(),
viewportSize = {
    width: 1200, height: 600
},
url = casper.cli.args[0],
ACfilename = casper.cli.args[1];

casper.start().zoom(1).thenOpen(url, function() {
...
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo('Finished captures for ' + url + ' at ' + ACfilename);
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time = end - start;
  this.echo('Computed time: ' + time/1000 + ' s').exit();
});
```

Everything is working great with my  js file but after casper execution the rest of the bat file isn't executed...

Anyone know from where this might comes and have a solution please? :)

Comment: Try `start /wait casperJS %1 %2 %3`

Comment: already tryied but start casperJS will launch a new cmd.exe and then I need to quit manually cmd to continue the script :(

Comment: What version of CasperJS and PhantomJS are you using? Also, if you're using the latest master branch of Casper, are you running the .exe file?

Comment: CasperJS v 1.0.3 and PhantomJS v 1.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of your .js file has nothing to do with the problem. CasperJS is launched via a batch file, `casperJS.bat`, so you must use `call casperJS %1 %2 %3` if you want to return to your batch script.